# Linked List Dealing with Strings, C

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I am trying to take an input (a word/string) from a user and store it in my linked list, however when I print my list, the program ends. I am very new to C language, any advice or articles to help me will be much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
  int data, index;
  char text[255];
  struct node* next;
};

//Global Variables
struct node* root = NULL;

//Prototypes
void insertA();
void insertB();
void prn();

//Main
void main () {
  char command[4];
  int num;
  char text[255];

  while(1) {
    printf("Command? "); //assume we know the key words
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s", &command);

    //Reads input and selects which command to execute
    if (strcmp(command, "insertA")==0) {
    scanf("%s", &text);
      insertA(text);
    } else
    if(strcmp(command, "insertB")==0) {
      scanf("%s", &text);
      insertB(num);
    } else
    if (strcmp(command, "prn")==0) {
      prn();
    } else
    if (strcmp(command, "end")==0) {
      exit(1);
    }
    else {
      return;
    }
  }
}

//Command Insert After
void insertA(char* text) {
  struct node* temp;
  temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  temp->data = text;
  temp->next = NULL;

  //Function if link does not exist, creates one
  if(root==NULL) {
    root = temp;
    printf("Text inserted at beginning\n");
  }
  //If link exists, adds to the end
  else {
    struct node* p;
    p = root;

    while(p->next != NULL) {
      p = p->next;
    }
    p->next = temp;
      printf("Ok\n");

  }
}

//Command Insert Before
void insertB(char* text) {
  struct node* temp;
  temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  temp->data = text;
  temp->next=NULL;
  //Function if link does not exist, creates one
  if (root == NULL) {
    root = temp;
    printf("Text inserted at beginning\n");
    fflush(stdout);
  }
  //If link exists, add to beginning
  else {
    temp->next=root;
    root = temp;
    printf("Ok\n");
    fflush(stdout) ;
  }
}

//Command Print
void prn() {
  struct node* temp;
  temp = root;
  int i=1;

  if(temp == NULL) {
    printf("List is empty\n");
    fflush(stdout);
  }
  else {
    while(temp != NULL) {
      printf("%d. ", i);
      printf("%s\n",temp->data);
      temp = temp->next;
      i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

I am going to attach the screenshot of the output I get [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLEwQ.png) so you can see what is happening

Comment: Use strcpy() or strncpy() in insert function.  strcpy(temp->data,text);

Comment: @user2181624 When I do that, the program exits after I put in my input

Comment: https://www.onlinegdb.com/S1FCSehRb

Comment: regarding statements like: `scanf("%s", &command);`  1)  always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest: `if( 1 != scanf("%s", &command) ) { // handle error and exit }  // implied else, scanf successful`  2) when using the input format specifiers: `%[...]` and `%s`, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer (because those specifiers always append a NUL byte) to avoid input buffer overflow which is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the 'command' strings, like "insertA" are actually 8 characters long.  So will not fit into a 4 character buffer.  Suggest making the buffer (at least) twice as long.

Comment: regarding: `printf("List is empty\n");
    fflush(stdout);`  no need to call `fflush(stdout);` when the format string is terminated with a '\n' as sending a newline has the same effect as calling that function.  Note: since the format string has no format specifiers, and `printf()` is a CPU cycle expensive function, suggest using: `puts( "List is empty", stdout );`  Note: `puts()` will always append a '\n' to the output so no need to have a newline at the end of the char string.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer, so no cast needed.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: nothing in the posted code informs the user as to what the valid commands are.  Suggest some kind of 'menu' be displayed inside the top of the while loop in `main()`

Comment: regarding: `void main () {`  This will cause most compilers (except Visual Studio) to output a warning message.   The function: `main()` only has two valid signatures: `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )` and `int main( void )`  Note that they all have a return type of `int`, not `void`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 4, 255.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Answer (score 1):

Your command buffer is only 4 bytes - How will "insertA" fit into that?

You are using `scanf()` to get the command. `scanf()` will fill the input buffer with a `'\n'` delimited string when you press enter, and then when it goes through its second round through the loop, your next scanf will read the newline first instead of whatever command you wanted to test.

If you want to safely reuse your `text` buffer, increase its size some and use `fgets()` to read your input into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `prn` function: the `data` attribute in the`node` struct is int as data type but in your `prn` function you use it as string; that's your wrong answer: causing the segmentation fault by `printf` function.
you only need to define well your attributes in the struct and use those correctly in your function.
i'll advice to study: pointers and double pointer, those get you a know how you can code better.

Answer (score 0):

your TEXT is a *char* variable while you defined data as *int*

```
struct node {
  int data, index;
  char text[255];
  struct node* next;
};
```

and in insertion you are doing `temp->data = text;` also in print fuction
you are doing `printf("%s\n",temp->data);` while temp->data is *int*